# How to get data from two database tables in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two tables which are following

```
contacts table
id
email
name
company
phone
```

and

```
signups table
id
contact_id
code
details
```

And I have two models `contacts` and `signups` and have same controllers as well.

What I want here is to get all data from contacts table where contacts table id = signups table contact_id.

How can I do this in ruby on rails?

**Update**

Here are my models which are empty for now

```
class Usercontacts < ActiveRecord::Base
#has_one :signups
#has_one :receiver, :class_name => "Signups"
end
```

HEre is second model

```
class Signups < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :contact_id, :code, :event_id, :details

 #belongs_to :usercontacts
 #belongs_to :receiver, :class_name => "Usercontacts"
end
```

**Now I am doing something like this my signups controller**

```
class SignupsController < ApplicationController
layout 'admin_layout'

def signups
    #@signups = Contact.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN signups ON contacts.id = signups.contact_id')
            @contacts = Contact.joins(:sign)
end
end
```

but this gets all the data from contacts table. but I want to get only that data which is whose id is present in signups table.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html, will be a good starting point.

Comment: And this too: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables

Comment: What do your models look like? What have you tried? You have to show some effort and not expect people to write your code for you.

Answer (score 5):

you are not following rails conventions

`Usercontacts` should be `UserContact` with corresponding table name `user_contacts`(or `Contact` if you already have `contacts` table)

`Signups` should be `Signup` with corresponding table name `signups`

relation declarations follow same conventions - `belongs_to :singular_name`, `has_many :plural_name`

if you start following conventions all your problems will go away